# ¿Cómo puedo redondear un número en C#?

Tags: c#

Si la parte decimal de un número es mayor o igual a 0.50 que pase al inmediato superior, si es menor a 0.50 que se quede con el número base.

Por ejemplo si es 4,51 que pase a 5 y si es 4,49 que se quede en 4.

Answer (score 13):

Simplemente usa el método [`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Math.Round(4.49) // 4
Math.Round(4.51) // 5
```

El método tiene más opciones como cuantos decimales quieres (por defecto 0) y el tipo de redondeo utilizado.

Tener en cuenta que el tipo de redondeo que utiliza por defecto es "hacia el número par".  Si quieres el redondeo básico:

```
Math.Round(2.5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 3
Math.Round(2.5); // 2
```