# Redondear después del punto de un float

Tags: c#

Presento un problema: Necesito hallar el área de un circulo (el valor lo digita el usuario) pero necesitto que después del punto se redondé el resultado. A continuación el código y ejemplos:

```
float pi = 3.14159f;
        float radio = 0.0f;
        float area = 0f;
        radio = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        area = pi * radio * radio;

        Console.WriteLine("A=" + area + "\r\n");
```

Ejemplo:

El usuario digita: 2.00 /resultado/ A=12.56636
Necesito que después del punto se redondee ese resultado.

Comment: Es decir, ¿deseas que el área sea 13?

Comment: Se redondee a que? 1 decimal? 2 decimales? un entero? para arriba? para abajo?

Comment: @fredyfx No amigo, necesito que se redondee despues del punto ej: ("12.5664")

Comment: @gbianchi Neceisto que despues del punto se redondee en 4 decimale ej ("12.5664") y no así: ("12.56636")

Comment: Y eso era justamente lo que tenias que poner en la pregunta...

Comment: Duplicado? [Cómo puedo redondear un número en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7568/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-redondear-un-n%c3%bamero-en-c)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pedir que solo se muestre la parte entera formateando la salida...

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        float pi = 3.14159f;
        float radio = 0.0f;
        float area = 0f;
        radio = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        area = pi * radio * radio;
        var areaRedondeada = Math.Round(area,4); //Redondea a 4 digitos
        Console.WriteLine(areaRedondeada);  //Lo muestra (internamente ya está redondeado)
        Console.WriteLine("A={0:0.0000}\r\n",area); //Redondea a 4 decimales sólo para salida.
    }
}
```

El resultado será 12.5664 para el caso que comentas.

Puedes verlo funcionando acá https://dotnetfiddle.net/7f4bd8

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu respuesta, el problema está en que s necesito que sea float; No debe ser ("13") sino: ("12.5664") Debe redondear después del punto.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el método `Math.Round()`.
Entre otras sobrecargas, admite un `float` o `double` como primer argumento y un `int` como segundo, el cual será el número de decimales a redondear.

```
int decimals = 4;
float rounded = Math.Round(radio, decimals);
```

Pasando `4` como segundo parámetro, si `radio` es `12.56636f`, el resultado (en `rounded`) será `12.5664`.

[Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1) dejo más información sobre el método.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por la respuesta; Ahí se estaría devolviendo: ("12.5664") lo que necesito es que despues del punto se redondee

Comment: Puedes añadirle como segundo parámetro cuántos decimales necesitas que tenga, como he mencionado. Si no quieres que tenga ningún decimal puedes pasar por argumento un `0` o directamente llamar a `Math.Round(radio);`